# Using Scala and Spark Apply "like" operator with multiple string (Seq or Array etc). on a DataFrame

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, seq

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Apple"),("Banana"),("Graphes"),("Pineapple"))).toDF("col1")
val s = Seq("Ban%","Grap%")
```

**Output Should be like below**

| col1 |
| --- |
| Banana |
| Graphes |

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Apple"),("Banana"),("Graphes"),("Pineapple"))).toDF("col1")
val s = Seq("Ban%","Grap%")
val likeString = s.map(x=> s"""col1 like "$x" or""").mkString(" ")
df.filter(likeString.substring(0, likeString.length-2)).show
```

**Output**

| col1 |
| --- |
| Banana |
| Graphes |

You can replace with below as well

```
val likeString = s.mkString("col1 like '","' or  col1 like '","' ")
df.filter(likeString).show
```